# "Spinning wheels" - Animated spinner with SVG and Sass-CSS

Tags: css, animation, sass, svg

I've made this little animation using SVG, CSS-keyframes and a bit of Sass.

```css
html,
body,
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
svg {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
circle {
  position: absolute;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 50px;
  stroke-dasharray: 31.5;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  stroke: #00aadd;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: turn-circle 5s linear infinite;
}
circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  stroke: #00ab02;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: turn-circle 4s linear infinite;
}
circle:nth-of-type(3) {
  stroke: #0053FF;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: turn-circle 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes turn-circle {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <svg version="1.1">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" />
    <circle cx="330" cy="150" r="100" />
    <circle cx="240" cy="220" r="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here's the uncompiled Sass-code:

```css
$backgroundColor:#efefef;
 $blue:#0053FF;
 $green:#00ab02;
 $cyan:#00aadd;
@mixin setCircle ($i:1,
$color:blue,
$zIndex:0,
$animationDuration:3s) {
  circle: nth-of-type(# {
    $i
  }
  ) {
    stroke: $color;
    z-index: $zIndex;
    animation: turn-circle # {
      $animationDuration
    }
    s linear infinite;
  }
}
html,
body,
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: $backgroundColor;
}
svg {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
circle {
  position: absolute;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 50px;
  stroke-dasharray: 31.5;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@include setCircle (1,
$cyan,
0,
5);
@include setCircle (2,
$green,
1,
4);
@include setCircle (3,
$blue,
2,
3);
@keyframes turn-circle {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

It works and looks alright but could surely be improved.

Therefore my questions:

- Could one improve the movement of the wheels in a way that it looks better? More natural?
- **How could the responsiveness be improved?** Currently my main issue.
- Suggestions concerning the design? I'm an amateur in that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totaly refactored your code (CSS and HTML). I wont address all the modifications and focus on the main ones :

### Browser support

The is an issue in firefox when a percentage `transform-origin` is set on an svg element.If you test your code in FFF, you will see the circles are rotating around the center of the SVG element.
To get around this, I put each circle in a seperate svg element and set the rotation on the svg element itself.

### Horizontal and vertical centering

I changed the absolute positionning technique to flexbox as it is more flexible espacialy as you plan on making this responsive.

### Responsive

I use the first svg to set the size of the `.wrap` element. The other ones adapt their size according to the first one with absolute positioning and percentage sizes.

I also tidied up the code

- remove positioning on the `circle` element
- removed the z-index as the layers are set with the order of the elements in the markup

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { 
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #efefef; 
}
.wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:10% 0;
 }
svg {
  width: 70%;
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  animation: turn-circle 5s linear infinite;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 50;
  stroke-dasharray: 31.5;
}
svg:nth-of-type(1){
  position:static;
  margin:-15% 0 0 -5%;
  stroke: #00aadd;
}
svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  stroke: #00ab02;
  top:0;
  right:-5%;
  animation-duration:4s;
}
svg:nth-of-type(3) {
  stroke: #0053FF;
  top:20%; left:15%;
  animation-duration:3s;
}
@keyframes turn-circle {
  to { -weblit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);
               transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 300 300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" />
  </svg>
  <svg version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 300 300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" />
  </svg>
  <svg version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 300 300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" />
  </svg>  
</div>
```